# Changing the options in an HTML select element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want a user to enter their birthday using three select menus. When a user enters their month of birth the options in the "Day" menu should change to fit that month (January has 31 days while April has 30). My current solution involves creating new pre-defined option elements using a "for" loop that is splitting an array. Currently, There are no changes to the webpage when I select "January" from the drop-down.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
if(s1.value == 'january'{
var optionArray = ["|", "1|1", "2|2", "3|3", "4|4", "5|5", "6|6", "7|7", "8|8", "9|9", "10|10","11|11", "12|12", "13|13", "14|14", "15|15", "16|16", "17|17", "18|18", "19|19", "20|20", "21|21", "22|22", "23|23", "24|24", "25|25", "26|26", "27|27", "28|28", "29|29","30|30", "31|31"];
}else{
}
for(option in optionArray){
var pair = 'optionArray.split['|'];
var newOption = dcoument.createElement('option');
newOption.value = pair[0];
newOption.innerHTML = pair[1]; 
s2.options.add(newOption);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Date of Birth<select id = 'slct1' name = 'slct1' 
onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
                <option value = ""></option>
                <option value = 'january'>January</option>
<select id = 'slct2' name='slct2'></select>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be done easily with jquery. or you can use moment.js for such functionality without much effort

Comment: I think it's better to use a dictionary instead of optionArray variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to your problem. I changed the code a little bit. The solution uses pure javascript. After declaring the function I just ran the function for initialization. For this purpose, the second select tag must be present. So make sure to put script at the end of body tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    Date of Birth<select id='slct1' name='slct1' onchange="populate()">
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March">March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
                <option value="June">June</option>
                <option value="July">July</option>
                <option value="August">August</option>
                <option value="September">September</option>
                <option value="October">October</option>
                <option value="November">November</option>
                <option value="December">December</option>
                </select>
    <select id='slct2' name='slct2'></select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var daysInMonth = {
            "January": 31,
            "February": 28,
            "March": 31,
            "April": 30,
            "May": 31,
            "June": 30,
            "July": 31,
            "August": 31,
            "September": 30,
            "October": 31,
            "November": 30,
            "December": 31
        };

        function populate() {
            var s1 = document.getElementById('slct1');
            var s2 = document.getElementById('slct2');
            s2.innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < daysInMonth[s1.value]; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = i + 1;
                s2.add(option);
            }

        }
        populate(); // init
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```